# How to solve this kind of surface integral with Hamilton Operator?

Tags: calculus, integration, surface-integrals, curl

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, $f=\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^2$, Surface $S$ is defined by $S=\{(x,y,z)|f(x,y,z)=1, z>0\}$, and the vector field $A$ is defined by $A=(yz,x^3(z+1),x^2+y^2)^T$, where T is short for the transfer of a vector.

How to solve the integrate $$\int_S(\nabla\times A)\cdot\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}dS$$ where dS is the area element of surface S and $\nabla$ is the Hamilton Operator.

I have checked the book to find that $\nabla\times A$ denotes the curl of A, which formula is here: [curl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIwLQ.png). But I don't know how to deal with dS in this surface integral.

Comment: Perhaps you may check [this topic](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/SurfIntVectorField.aspx) regarding Surface Integrals of vector fields (of second kind).

Comment: Since $S$ is a surface where $f \equiv 1$, $\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ is unit normal vector for $S$. you can apply [divergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem)  and...